# github - Possible to have a sub-project that only subscribes to part of the target project?

Tags: git, github, subproject

I'd like to set up a git sub-project that pulls in just one file from the target project - I just want to pull in the built JavaScript library from the target project, not the whole project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: no, but it might help to perform a shallow clone (get only the last N commits). Look at `git clone --depth MAXDEPTH`.